# Does Javascript OAuth not work in IE for Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

As far as I can tell, it's impossible to do OAuth authentication with the Drive API in Javascript in IE. Take the simplest authentication code imaginable:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script>
      function auth() {
        var config = {
          'client_id': 'YOUR CLIENT ID',
          'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener'
        };
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
          console.log('login complete');
          console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="auth();">Authorize</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will work in IE, provided you provide your own client ID. Now change the 'scope' variable to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'. If you try to test this in IE, you should see that the JS library will bomb and fail to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Drive SDK/API in api console?

Go to Google APIs Console -> Services -> and turn on Drive SDK and Drive API.

This is one of the reason why drive sdk scope does not work while score for [urlshorter](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener) works.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, and I should add that I've gotten this sample working in Google Chrome.